# How do I use JSON element with alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am using two textfields to pass login information to the PHP web service using Alamofire in the following way.

```
    @IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: Any) {

   //getting the username and password
    let parameters: Parameters=[
    "Name":TextFieldUserName.text!,
    "Pass":TextFieldPassword.text!
    ]

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
    {
    response in
  //printing response
    print(response)
```

The following Json data is received on login.

```
[{"code":0,"message":"Check Username and Password....","userid":""}]
```

I want to use either "code" value (0 for false and 1 for true) or "message" value as String to put into an if - else statement for further steps. If Alamofire is not the best way to go about this, can someone please show another way. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to deserialize the response from the server?

The easiest option is parsing response value as NSDictionary

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
    let code = JSON.value(forKey: "code") as? Int
    let message = JSON.value(forKey: "message") as? String
}
```

You can also use the Codable protocol and the JSONDecoder to decode this response into your structure.

For example, declare struct:

```
struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    var code: Int
    var message: String
}
```

and decode response using JSONDecoder

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let loginResponse = try? jsonDecoder.decode(LoginResponse.self, from: response.data)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. However when I print(JSON) or print(code) or print(message)I get a blank output. Can you please help me?

Comment: @EdwinJoseph Do u see json output if u write it? :    if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
    print("JSON: \(json)")
}

Comment: also write value of response.result, maybe the request failed

Comment: I don't see any output when I write: if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] { print("JSON: (json)") }

Comment: @EdwinJosephso maybe request was failed, check it. and maybe some debug alamofire request errors exists

Comment: @EdwinJoseph your LOGIN URL have https? if not - did u add your domain at App Transport Security Settings in info.plist?

Comment: it has http not https. Do I still need to do it?

Comment: @EdwinJoseph 
You have to set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31807139/6583801

Comment: @EdwinJoseph for details we need to watch debug logs